# How to Rules for TFS 2012 file checkin

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

I need to set rules while check in files in TFS.

**Rules:** 
At least one work item should mapped to the check in file.
the user can map only assigned work item

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add check-in policy of type work Items, see the following image,

[image]